# With Matplotlib, if I have f(x) and g(x) how can I plot g as a function of f or viceversa

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Let's say I have an algorithm that estimates a value over time (x), f(x) is the estimation error. I also have g(x) that should indicate how good/promising is x to perform an estimation, as in, the higher g(x), the lower f(x), let's call this fitness.

Basically, I can plot f(x) and g(x) by calling, for example:

```
ax0.plot(time, f_data, 'g-', label='f over time')
ax0.plot(time, g_data, 'g-', label='g over time')
```

I can see by comparing these two plots how good is the correlation between f and g, but I want to be able to plot one as a function of the other, basically, what I would hope to obtain by plotting the estimation error as a function of the fitness is a somewhat linear decreasing function.

How could I do this? I cannot just say f_data.sort() and g_data.sort(). What I would need is to sort g_data (the fitness) and have f_data "follow" the same order. That is, have g_data while still having that the g_data[i] and f_data[i] still maintain the same time(x).

Although the result is more mathematical I feel like the main problem here is performing this sort properly, or maybe there is an easier way to obtain this using matplotlib.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I see you've not accepted or upvoted any of the answers to your previous questions. For many reasons it's helpful to do so, and it is a critical part of how SO works. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) are short overviews.

Comment: @tom10 okay thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about [parametric curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation).  To plot them, what you'll want to do is generate both `f[i]` and `g[i]`, where each element in the sequences have the same parameter value; then you'll be able to say that when *f* has the value `f[101]` *g* will have the value `g[101]`.

The classic is *f(t) = cos(t)* and *g(t) = sin(t)*:

[image]

```
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
f = np.cos(t)
g = np.sin(t)

plt.plot(f, g)
plt.xlabel("f")
plt.ylabel("g")
```

As you suggest in your question, these types of plots of very useful for seeing the relationship between two values.

For example, say *f* is phase shifted, so it's more aligned with *g*, then you'd get

```
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
f = np.cos(t + .45*np.pi)  # shift the phase of f
g = np.sin(t)
```

[image]

(On review, in this image, I just noticed that I shifted the phase the wrong way in the example, so the curves aren't "more aligned" as I had intended, but are becoming anti-aligned, so the peaks of *f* are occurring closer to the troughs of *g*.  If they were more aligned, the curve would have a positive slope, up and to the right.)